# How to show images of JSON object in a web browser?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, web

I'm using bing image search api in python which returns me a json object which has urls of images in it. I want to print that urls as a thumbnail or image in a web browser? How can I do it?

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, {}, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page
```

JSON return me output some thing like this...

```
 "hostPageUrl": "http:\/\/www.bing.com\/cr?                            IG=0644661E90174FF0944669467BB395AC&CID=138A535946A560B83BE859564794619A&rd=1&h=13FbTtiOoEUhU2CsArQ07IbXxNhi-nNDQ6fPq7MWTQU&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fwww.wsllpaper.com%2fmunchkin-cat-pictures-hd-desktop-wallpaper.html&p=DevEx,5091.1", "contentSize": "519962 B", "encodingFormat": "jpeg", "hostPageDisplayUrl": "www.wsllpaper.com\/munchkin-cat-pictures-hd-desktop-wallpaper.html", "width": 2048, "height": 1536, "thumbnail": {"width": 300, "height": 225}, "imageInsightsToken": "ccid_RKtlG1SO*mid_4EB4BDF5CB93430D44C13AB68064BC296B6593BE*simid_608043795625871665", "imageId": "4EB4BDF5CB93430D44C13AB68064BC296B6593BE", "accentColor": "496A82"},
```

Comment: can you please post the json structure

Comment: post your code in question

Comment: Do you mean whole output?

Comment: posted code and also some part of JSON return value

Comment: maybe first convert JSON string into python dictionary - ie. `dictionary = json.loads(the_page)` And then you can easily get urls from dictionary and generate HTML with tags `<img>`

Comment: Please give me more precise answer..... or show me some code if available?

Answer (score 0):

Base on your question I am assuming you need a front end piece.
To do in a web browser you would need a html tag img src="" alt="". The src is pretty much a URL where the image is located. You can visit http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Comment: i do not need this I have just edited my question please tell me about this